# How to deactivate the welcome screen in LibreOffice for Mac?

Tags: libreoffice

LibreOffice for mac - by default - starts with a welcome screen. While this might be useful to some, it also results in resume not working in Lion (I assume). No previous documents are being opened. **Can I deactivate this welcome screen?**

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I would sooner assume LibreOffice does not support Resume because, well, it's not written to support Resume. Resume is not some automatic special feature OS X enforces on apps, apps have to be written to take advantage of it.

Comment: This would be better as 2 separate questions.

Comment: Ok, I'll remove the second part for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no known setting to disable this dialog.

The "welcome screen" serves as a dispatcher to the different parts of LibreOffice (such as the word processor or spreadsheet). Because these applications cannot be accessed directly (they lack stand-alone binaries), the welcome screen is in fact quite functional when not launching LibreOffice from an existing document. Disabling it would not make much sense from a useability point a view, therefore I am not really surprised there is no setting to change this behavior.